# Tabhost in nested fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

MY project consists of a `navigation drawer` which i designed as one activity and several `fragments` now in my second fragment i have to design a `tab-host`  which has two other child fragment.

If anyone has a good example please share with with me. I don't want to use any external libraries for this because it will again effect my complete project